# Both local Server and Online Sever with same datastamp but results differ Mysql-Php

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a script for one of my websites where the vendor listing will appear on the website ONLY when the publish date they set example "02/15/2019" is met. So if the date they select is "02/18/2019" then the listing will not appear.

However, on my local server the script works perfectly fine as my current date is indeed the 16th of february and I also checked my online server date which is the same. However, when I try the same script on my online server, it doesn't show the listing EXCEPT if it is a date earlier. So if a post is schedule or published date is set to the 15th of this month, it doesn't show, however if I put the 15th, then it shows. using the string to time php function as seen below.

```
 $posteddate=date("m/d/Y");
 $todaysdate=strtotime("$posteddate");
```

and my mysql query has 
    ......AND thedeal.publish_date <= $todaysdate.......

so in essence the script is saying show listings where the publish date or date scheduled is less than or is the same date as todays date.

Yes I did contact my online server host and this is beyond them. any suggestions?

Comment: What DataType is the `publish_date` column defined as?

Comment: publish_date is varchar with a strtotime converted timestamp. example "1550206800" just as the result of strtotime("$posteddate");

Comment: WHY? Why not us a TIMESTAMP column

Answer (score 1):

Check your server timezone it must be different on your local and server. Time store in database in UTC so it show different value on server and local.

Comment: will check with them.

Comment: it was actually their issue as their timezone was set differently and was several hours off from mine. so they have fixed that on their part. thanks again.